# Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to figure out why all of the sudden i get an error when trying to run my program. The following code below is where the error is:

```
 <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> Partial Class frmPM
```

The error i get is highlighted on the frmPM:

```
 An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.
 The error is: Object variable or With block variable not set.
```

I've made sure there was a **End Class** at the end of all that but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

What else could cause this as it worked just fine for one run then not on down the road?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Do you have more code samples?  And what does the `Exception.InnerException` have to say?

Comment: You're probably attempting to access a member of a null reference.  Show us the line with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it seems as though it was creating a bad object at run time in a sub it was calling when it first started. Though its odd that it would have that type of error but after i commented that out, it seemed to work just fine. :o)